# Read shader node data from *.blender file by using external python

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have *.blend file and would like to read materials data from it by using standalone Python 2.7. I am using Blender File module from [here](https://developer.blender.org/source/blender-file/). It allows to read data from blender files. But I can't find a way to read all parameters of each shader node in the node tree.

For example, I have a very simple material with one GlossyBSDF node connected to the Surface port of the Material Output. This node contains four parameters: Distribution, Color, Roughness and Normal. When I enumerate inputs of this node, I obtain only three parameters (without Distribution). So, the first question: how to get access to all parameters of the node?

Also I can't get values of the node parameters. There is a property default_value for each socket object, but I can't understand how to use it. So, the second question: how it is properly to get access to parameters values?